# I need a list of registry predefined key values

Tags: registry

Google is failing me.

I need a list of the values that go with these predefined keys:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/predefined-keys

I got this one:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE    => 0x80000002;
```

But don't know the rest

:'(

-T

Answer (score 0):

The silly dialog box wants 30 characters, so this rambling should do fine:

https://www.originlab.com/doc/OriginC/ref/Registry-Registry